# make array reserve without changing array keys

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [28] => Array
        (
            [menuitem_id] => 28
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [menuitem_id] => 26
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [menuitem_id] => 25
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [menuitem_id] => 20
            [sub_item] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [item_id] => 3
                            [qty] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have this array out put now i need to reverse the array but without changing its keys. i like to start the foreach loop from last array to first. 
thanks

Comment: Please, use `var_export` instead of `var_dump`, so your array can be copy/pasted.

Answer (score 4):

`array array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = FALSE ] )`

> **preserve_keys**
>   If set to TRUE numeric keys are preserved. Non-numeric keys are not affected by this setting and will always be preserved.

e.g.

`array_reverse($input, true);`

See [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)